# Simplest way to fill working day table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table `working_days` with one column `date` of type date

I need to fill it with working days in USA.

Can you suggest how can I so this?

Manually it is too long.

Comment: Please tag your question with your database.  What constitutes a working day?  Weekends?  Holidays?

Comment: Have a calendar table instead, with all dates. (Where you tag each day as working day, national holiday etc.)

Comment: @sgeddes tagged as ms sql. Working day is not Weekend and not holiday

Comment: @jarlh where can I find this information?

Comment: How many years do you need to have? Also holidays are different amongst different businesses so you'd have to have some logic there. Getting the weekends is simple enough.

Comment: @SQLChao 2016 only. all days exclude weekends will be fine

Comment: @SQLChao Almost at the same time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to accomplish this. This only excludes the weekends. Using `DATEFIRST` you can figure out what day is a weekend. This query should work no matter what day of the week is set to `DATEFIRST`.

```
;WITH DatesCTE
 AS (

   SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS [workingDays]
   UNION ALL

   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays)
   FROM DatesCTE
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays) < '2017-01-01'

)

SELECT *
FROM DatesCTE
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

Answer (score 2):

At first fill your table with all dates for year (for example 2016):

```
DECLARE @date_start date = '2016-01-01',
        @date_end date = '2016-12-31';

WITH cte as (
SELECT @date_start as [d], 0 as Level
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,[d]), [level] + 1 as [level]
from cte
WHERE [level] < DATEDIFF(day,@date_start,@date_end)
),

holidays as ( --table with holidays
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('2016-01-01'),
('2016-01-18'),
('2016-02-15'),
('2016-05-30'),
('2016-07-04'),
('2016-09-05'),
('2016-10-10'),
('2016-11-11'),
('2016-11-24'),
('2016-12-26')) as t(d)
)

SELECT c.d
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN holidays h on c.d=h.d
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,d) NOT IN (1,7)  --will show only monday-friday
AND AND h.d is NULL
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000); --if you need more than 3 years get MAXRECURSION up
```

Comment: Or just add `and d not in ('20160704', '20161225', ...)`

Comment: This query come in handy to my own table with holidays/working days.

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop will do:

```
declare @d date = '20160101';
while @d <= '20161231'
begin
    if datepart(weekday, @d) not in (1, 7) and <@d not a holiday>
        insert into working_days ("date") values (@d);
    set @d = dateadd(day, 1, @d);
end
```