# Implementing Holidays in an Employee Management System

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, webforms

I'm working on an **Employee Management System** where employees can

- Clock in/Clock Out (Mark daily attendance)
- Apply for Leaves i.e. Sick
- Generate Reports i.e. Thier daily check in/Check out time, Total Worked Hours etc.

Now I have to introduce a way to deal with public holidays and employee absentees in these reports. I read a few articles online such as

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262272/integrating-holidays-and-attendance-in-an-hr-management-system

but I couldn't figure out anything. My questions are basically.

- What is the best way to deal with an employee being absent? Considering the fact that on that particular day an employee will not check in.
- How to Add/specify Weekend/Public Holidays in reports? As changing public/regular holidays in the future may well affect our reports of the previous months.

I'd really appreciate some help here! 
Thank you

Comment: 1. you will need a calendar table. It contains all possible dates (past & future). 2. first, what do you want to do if an employee is absent ? then you think about how to deal with it

Comment: @squirrel Thank you for your comment. What exactly do you recommend to do with a calendar table? 
Secondly, i'm not actually sure what to do when an employee is absent. That is why i'm here in the first place.

Comment: _"What do you recommend to do with a calendar table?"_ - populate it with information about any day - whether it is a holiday or something else. The only purpose of `calendar` table is to be used as calendar in your program.

Comment: @ivanStarostin what if a particular holiday date gets changed? It will affect the precious reports. No?

Comment: What do you mean? `2016-07-25 - holiday`, `2017-07-25 - not holiday` who affects who? Year later someone will say *"you know, I did not enjoy that party, let's say it was not a holiday"*?..

Comment: @Squirreli I agree about the calendar table but disagree with the All possible dates, what he needs is all active dates, so as clocking happens only on a daily basis dates between the first clocking and today are required, absences need to be recorded on a daily basis so you need all days between start and end date, but no way you need every date ever

Comment: @MikeT Calendar table for 10 years would have 3652 rows. Why not?

Comment: @IvanStarostin because then you are building in a fail point that requires human interaction to correct, i admit that most systems rarely last 10 years, but in a former job there was a employee and client database both built in the 1980's that were still in use, both of which were constantly falling over because no one had bothered to take into account that the system might out last their employment at the company.

Comment: @MikeT I'm saying that _even table for 10 years_ would have such insignificant amount of data. What's the problem of keeping there all the passed year? Current whole year? It would require human interaction to correct what? And what would be the difference with `active dates` table in this case?

Comment: @IvanStarostin and i'm agreeing that its not signifacant volume of data, i'm saying that pre-populating with the lifespan of the system is limiting the lifetime of the system because in 10years time the system will fail unless someone remembers to go top up the date table, better to put in place a automated system that will automatically top up the table as required either on demand or at predefined periods, say once a month topping up the table to 13 months in the future if 12 months is maximum future usage. this takes out the human element and provides a more robust system

Comment: @MikeT I don't think that somebody (nor Squirrel neither I) ment to populate calendar table from 1900-01-01 till 3000-12-31.

Answer (score 2):

Very few (if any) databases deal with date ranges as a data type, and while there are ways to calculate date range intersections they are expensive and will cause any large datasets to crawl. thus you need to trade calculation speed for data storage

because of this the best way to check is to have a table that stores dates, then use the dates in that table to inflate your date ranges to all dates inside the range, the structure is simple just a single column with the date in it

i would not suggest using the date table to keep track of holidays instead just include these as absences of type "Public Holiday" you may want to mark weekends (or what day of the week it is) in the datetable but don't use that to say whether a person did or didn't work that day instead have a workingPattern table that says employee of type `factory worker` works 4 hours on a monday, 6 hours on a tuesday. this will then give you an employees expected working hours and which days they are expected to work in a week with out forcing every employ to follow the same working pattern

eg

```
select d.Date, a.*
from absence as a
join dates as d on d.Date between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
```

this will then give you every date that the person is absent allowing you you very easily compare different absence periods together

most employ systems rarely allow employees to work more than a year in advance, so I would **suggest** having a monthly job that runs and populates the date table with all dates between `(Today + 12 months)` and `(Today + 13 months)` you can also delete old dates but before doing so make sure there are no circumstances where you will need to query the data. ie everything before the min date you are leaving has been archived.

The next thing to keep in mind is the human element, people will forget to clock in or out so you need to keep this in mind and have a daily job that looks for clock ins with out a matching clock out or visa versa, then you can either flag these for human correction or deal with them automatically

once you have these two elements sorted you can calculate each persons daily hours worked,cross join that to the daily absence view, which will allow you to check for inconsistency like dates on the Date table that have no clockings or absence (unauthorised absence) that can be corrected with appropriate entries into the absence table or clashes such as someone coming into work when they should have been on holiday, again you can flag for human correction or handle automatically, say if clocking is present ignore absence

How you actually build your system depends on what you need in your systems but these are the common factors that will kill your system if you don't take them into account

Answer (score 1):

I was writing a comment, but that gone to far and I considered to write an answer.

> How to Add/specify Weekend/Public Holidays in reports?

You can use a table (like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725977/simplest-way-to-fill-working-day-table/35726743)) to store all days of the given year with flag is a day working or not. We use something like this in our environment. It is filled manually once a year.

> What is the best way to deal with an employee being absent?

I bet there will be some table with rows like:

```
EmployeeID  InOut   Date                
1           In      2016-07-24 07:00:01.000
1           Out     2016-07-24 18:00:09.908
etc
```

So if Employee being absent - there will be no rows on particular date.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @gofr1.
This is really helpful, gave me a couple of perspectives to think from.

Comment: i would only disagree with "So if Employee being absent - there will be no rows on particular date" your forgetting about night shift, where someone clocks in one day and clocks out the next, you need to just check for In       or out not both

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to deal with an employee being absent? Considering the fact that on that particular day an employee will not check in.

You can make an initial setup/code file for this. There will be a specific table to hold the information about all the public holidays in the calendar year. It will be entered manually at the start of each year.

Now when the attendance data is processed it will check on dates. If any date would be present in that code file, It will be marked as holiday.

> How add specific holiday in reports?

Keeping in mind, you will need a table which will hold every date of the year and then a flag attribute with each date. A flag is set true/false based on working day/ holiday.

If the flag is false then there is a holiday and you will show the holiday in the reports. You can even set a column in this table to mention the name of the holiday. It will maintain the data for dates for every year. So if you want to see the attendance reports for previous year. The data would be there and there would be no problem.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as your duplicating functionality, the OP can't use this mechanism to store Sickness or holidays for a user, just record holidays in the same way as any other absence

Comment: There would be another table for leave management, initially an absent is marked for any employee not present. On process, if the employee has taken a leave then the attendance status will be changed to leave. And moreover there will be another field which will set the type of leave.

Comment: thats my point, if you have to have another table to do the same thing then you aren't following KIS, normalisation also requires that data be stored in as few places as possible with minimal duplication